# What is the degree of a symmetric boolean function?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, co.combinatorics, open-problems

(previous title " Zero sum of binomials coefficients - a stronger version ")
This is a stronger version of [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74045/zero-sum-of-binomial-coefficients).

Is there an $N\in \mathbb N$ and a sequence of non-constant functions $ \left\{ p_n:[n] \to \{ 1,-1 \} \right\}_{n=N} ^{\infty}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have:

$$ \sum _{i=0} ^{n} (-1)^{i}  p_n(i) \cdot \binom {n} {i} = 0$$

For instance, for all odd values of n, we may choose 
$p_{n}(i)=\begin{cases}
(-1)^{i} & i\leq\frac{n-1}{2}\\\
(-1)^{i+1} & i\geq\frac{n+1}{2}\end{cases}$. This simply means we sum the first half of the binomial coefficients and subtract the second half. The fact that for odd values we can partition the set of binomial coefficients evenly allows us to do that, so I don't see how the same trick may be applied for even values.

To my understanding, the methods that solved [the previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74045/zero-sum-of-binomial-coefficients) (for which I thank [darij grinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2530/darij-grinberg) and [Mikael de la Salle](https://mathoverflow.net/users/10265/mikael-de-la-salle)) are not applicable here.

My guess, as before, is that there is no such sequence (in which all functions are non-constant), any ideas on how to prove it?

(a counter example would surprise me, but is of interest as well)

Comment: What would you suggest for p_1 and p_2?  Gerhard "They Look Constant To Me" Paseman, 2011.08.31

Comment: I just noticed the big N.  Never miNd.  Gerhard "Time To Get Different Glasses" Paseman, 2011.08.31

Comment: For odd n the relation is satisfied if $p_n(i)+p_n(n-i)=0$ for all $i$. In this case, there are at least $\frac{n+1}{2}$ choices for pn. So your question concerns even $n$ only, right?

Comment: (with - instead of + I guess)

Comment: To make up for my earlier gaffe, notice that for p a prime, the pth, p+1st, and later rows have very few entries which are not 0 mod p.  (Indeed, mod p they look like 2 new copies of Pascal's triangle.)  This along with the frequency of primes suggests to me that you will not be able to get all the functions non constant.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.31

Comment: Yes Pietro, it concerns only even $n$, but I thought that a more detailed presentation would cloud the essence of the question.

Comment: Gerhard, would you mind going into details? I don't quite follow.

Comment: I don't really get it. Are you simply asking for which $n\geq 0$ we can partition the $n$-th row of the Pascal triangle (seen as a multiset) in two submultisets with equal sum, other than by putting the elements alternately in each of the two parts?

Comment: Let's take n=8.  Mod 7 the row is 1 1. 0 0 0 0 0 1 1, which says something about the end members of p_8.  But also nod 5, the row is 1 3 3 1 0 1 3 3 1, which implies additional constraints mod 5.  In general there will be for n=2k pi(2k) - pi(k) such constraints, which might be enough to pin p_2k down to a constant.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.31 

Comment: Darij, yes, this is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: On the $14$-th line of the Pascal triangle, we have $1-14+91-364-1001+2002-3003-3432+3003+2002+1001-364+91-14+1=0$. This leads to a nonconstant $p_{14}$. I am not sure whether this is a sporadic or a recurring phenomenon. Anyway I propose tagging the question "additive-number-theory".

Comment: A friend ran a computer simulation and found that for 16 and 18, for instance, we have no other option but to sum the coefficients with alternating signs (i.e. $(-1)^j$), that's what inspired the use of N, since it follows that even if there is such a sequence, then it must be that N>18.

(this is in part what leads me to believe that there is no such sequence)

Comment: P.S. - I'm not allowed to add new tags, and there's no 'additive-number-theory' tag.

Comment: Update: This is actually equivalent to a question I was trying to solve (about the n-th Fourier coefficient of symmetric boolean functions), that I just found is open, so I withdraw the question, as I understand this is not in accordance with MO guidelines.

Comment: I would not delete the question.  You can edit it and flag for moderator attention.  I recommend an open-problem tag and words in the question itself to reflect that.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.01 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was already pointed out in the comments that determining for which $n$ one can find a non-constant $p_n$ is an open problem. I thought I'd give a bit of context and my understanding on what is known so far. The problem as stated has a negative answer because when $n+1$ is prime, $p_n$ must be constant.

The sums $\sum_{i=0}^n \varepsilon_i \binom{n}{i}$ are the leading coefficients of the polynomials we get from Lagrange interpolation on points $(i,\alpha(i))$ where $0\le i\le n$ and $\alpha(i)\in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$. So the question is equivalent to

> Is there a polynomial that sends $\lbrace 0,1,\dots,n\rbrace$ to $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, that is not constant but has degree $\le n-1$?

Let us denote the number of such polynomials by $\mathcal B(n)$. Some examples are given by $\varepsilon_i=(-1)^i$ when $n$ is even and $\varepsilon_i=-\varepsilon_{n-i}$ for odd $n$. This implies that $\mathcal B(n)\geq 2$ when $n$ is even and $\mathcal B(n)\geq 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ when $n$ is odd. Finding non-trivial solutions to the problem implies improving on these lower bounds.

Here is a simple argument, that when $p$ is an odd prime $\mathcal B(p-1)=2$, so there are no non-trivial solutions. This is because $\binom{p-1}{i}\equiv (-1)^i\pmod{p}$ so the only way for the sum to be divisible by $p$ is if the sequence $(-1)^i\varepsilon_i$ is constant. This includes the examples $n=16,18$ that you confirmed with a computer search. However there are even values of $n$ for which $k(n)\geq 3$. The first example is
$$\binom{8}{0}-\binom{8}{1}-\binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{3}+\binom{8}{4}-\binom{8}{5}-\binom{8}{6}-\binom{8}{7}+\binom{8}{8}=0$$
and the next one is the one given by Darij in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74191/what-is-the-degree-of-a-symmetric-boolean-function#comment188980_74191) for $n=14$. The even values of $n$ for which $\mathcal B(n)\geq 3$ and $n\le 128$ were found in J. von zur Gathen and J. Roche, ["Polynomials with two values"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01215917), Combinatorica 17, no. 3 (1997), 345–362. The sequence is $\lbrace 24,34,48,54\rbrace$ and numbers $2\pmod{6}$.

Your question is really about proving that $\mathcal B(n)=2$ for infinitely many $n$, and it is an open to determine such $n$ besides the values found in the von Zur Gathen-Roche paper. As I mentioned above it is equivalent to proving for such $n$ that the minimum degree of a non-constant polynomial sending $\lbrace 0,1,\dots,n\rbrace\to \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ is $n$. The best results known so far are that the degree is $n-o(n)$, where the $o(n)$ comes from the gaps in consecutive primes (so one can take $O(n^{.525})$), but conjecturally this can be improved to $n-O(1)$.

One thing that is surprising is the following threshold phenomenon. If we look at non-constant polynomials sending $\lbrace 0,1,\dots,n\rbrace\to \lbrace 0,1,\dots,n\rbrace$, the minimum degree is $1$ (for instance $f(x)=x$), but as soon as we look at $\lbrace 0,1,\dots,n\rbrace\to \lbrace 0,1,\dots,n-1\rbrace$ the degree is at least $n-o(n)$. The current methods don't seem to make use of the fact that in the boolean case the range is simply $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$, as they give the same bound for larger ranges. A recent paper on the topic is ["On the Degree of Univariate Polynomials Over the Integers"](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00493-015-2987-0) by G. Cohen, A. Shpilka and A. Tal.

Comment: Thanks.
A useful reference is the survey of Buhrman and de Wolf on complexity measures of boolean functions, where current results and some proofs appear.

Comment: When looking at the Cohen-Shpilka-Tal paper I mentioned above you will see that the relevant results in Buhrman and de Wolf hold for a slightly more general setting, and they emphasize the point that current lower bounds on the degree come from mod p considerations and no technique is known that distinguishes between a very small range and a comparably sized range.

Comment: Your "simple argument" that there are no nontrivial ways to assign the signs for $n=p-1$, $p$ prime, solves the question as stated, since it shows that there is no $N$ so that there are nontrivial solutions for $n\gt N$. 

Comment: I agree with Douglas, why isn't your "simple argument" in fact showing that, as you wrote, B(n)=2 for infinitely many n?

Comment: Great, I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And here I was looking at p being 1+prime because I thought the light was better.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Missing Keys" Paseman, 2011.09.03