# Non-trivial alternating sums of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider a binary vector $a_0, a_1,\,\dots\,, a_n$ and an equation

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i \cdot (-1)^i {n \choose i} = 0.$$

You can satisfy this trivially when

1) all $a_i$ are 0, or

2) all $a_i$ are 1, or

3) $n$ is odd and $a$ satisfies $a_i = a_{n-i}$ for all $i$, because the summands for $i$ and $n-i$ cancel out.

My question is if there are any other vectors $a$ satisfying the equation?

[There has been a related [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74191/what-is-the-degree-of-a-symmetric-boolean-function) but regarding $a_i \in \{-1,1\}$. There are non-trivial examples given in the answers but they do not seem to work in this setup. I have also asked this at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445254/non-trivial-alternating-sums-of-binomial-coefficients) but then I read that this community if better suited for research-level questions.]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. If you have a solution with $a_i \in \{ -1, 1\}$, then you also have a solution with $a_i \in \{ 0, 1\}$ simply by replacing each $a_i$ with $(a_i + 1)/2$ (using the fact that setting all $a_i = 1$ is also a valid solution). Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Ira, the question asks for a *binary* vector, which I think means a vector whose entries are just zeros & ones.

Comment: @Gerry you're right—I deleted my comment.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Yes, you are totally right. So my question trivially reduces to an already addressed one. I guess I cannot mark a comment as a solution, but I would if you only post it as an answer.

Comment: The number of solutions for $n=1,2,3,\ldots,25$ is
$$
2,2,4,2,8,2,16,6,32,2,64,2,144,14,256,2,512,2,1024,6,2048,2,4096,50,8192.
$$
As the OP notes, it is easy to construct $2$ solutions for $n$ even, 
and $2^k$ solutions for $n=2k-1$;
but note that there are $16$ more for $n=13$.  The four extra solutions for
$n=8$ are obtained from $001001100$ (the identity
${8 \choose 2} - {8 \choose 5} + {8 \choose 6} = 0$ noted by **LeechLattice**)
by reflection and 1's complement; the twelve for $n=14$
are the orbits of $000001001110000, 000001100110000, 000010000110000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposting my comment as an answer, as requested by the OP.)

If you have a solution with $a_i \in \{−1,1\}$, then you also have a solution with $a_i \in \{0,1\}$ simply by replacing each $a_i$ with $(a_i+1)/2$ (using the fact that setting all $a_i=1$ is also a valid solution). In other words, your question had already been answered by some of the comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74191/what-is-the-degree-of-a-symmetric-boolean-function).

Answer (score 3):

What you have is the $n$-th difference operator applied to the sequence $(a_i)$.

In particular, the value is 0 if $a_i=f(i)$ for any polynomial $f$ of degree less than $n$.

The converse is also true.  If the sum is 0 it means that the $n$-th difference is 0, which means there is a polynomial $f$ of degree less than $n$ such that $a_i=f(i)$ for all $i$.  This is therefore a complete characterisation.

Answer (score 2):

${8\choose{2}}-{8\choose{5}}+{8\choose{6}}=28-56+28=0$, so there's a solution for $n=8$.

Comment: More generally: if $k$ is odd, then $$ \binom{3k - 1}{k-1} - \binom{3k-1}{k} + \binom{3k-1}{2k} = 0$$ the case $k = 1$ is a trivial case. This answer was $k = 2$.

Comment: The next $k$ with $k = 3$ has $3k-1 = 14$ and is related to the sum mentioned in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74191/what-is-the-degree-of-a-symmetric-boolean-function#comment188980_74191)

Answer (score 2):

The binomial coefficients ${n\choose k-1}, {n\choose k}$, and ${n\choose k+1}$ are in arithmetic progression if and only if $n=m^2-2$ and $k=\frac 12(n-m)$ or $\frac 12(n+m)$. For such $n$ and $k$ we have
     $$ {n\choose k-1}-{n\choose k}+{n\choose k+1}-{n\choose n-k}=0. $$

Answer (score -1):

We may similarly wonder whether any partial sums in the trinomial expansion

$$(1+z+z^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {n \choose k}_{\!2}z^k$$

could be $0$ when $z = e^{2i\pi/3}$ cancels the whole. The answer is positive too :

$${5 \choose 2}_{\!2}z^2+{5 \choose 3}_{\!2}+{5 \choose 7}_{\!2}z+{5 \choose 8}_{\!2}z^2 =
15z^2+30+30z+15z^2 = 0$$

.
$${11 \choose 0}_{\!2} + {11 \choose 4}_{\!2}z + {11 \choose 6}_{\!2} + {11 \choose 9}_{\!2} + {11 \choose 11}_{\!2}z^2 + \\{11 \choose 13}_{\!2}z + {11 \choose 16}_{\!2}z + {11 \choose 18}_{\!2} + {11 \choose 22}_{\!2}z =\\
1+880z+4917+19855+25653z^2+19855z+4917z+880+z = 0$$

.
$${13 \choose 1}_{\!2}z+{13 \choose 3}_{\!2}+{13 \choose 5}_{\!2}z^2+{13 \choose 8}_{\!2}z^2+{13 \choose 10}_{\!2}z+{13 \choose 12}_{\!2}+\\
{13 \choose 14}_{\!2}z^2+{13 \choose 16}_{\!2}z+{13 \choose 18}_{\!2}+{13 \choose 21}_{\!2}+{13 \choose 23}_{\!2}z^2+{13 \choose 25}_{\!2}z =\\
13z + 442 + 5005z^2 + 52624z^2 + 129844z + 201643 + \\
201643z^2 + 129844z + 52624 + 5005 + 442z^2 + 13z = 0$$